# Is it possible to make changes to WCF RIA entities on the server, send them to the client but not affect the underlying entities?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

From reading the title it might seem like an odd request, so let me clarify.

I'm storing dates and times on the server alongside their time zone information. I want the clients to be able to request these objects with a parameter matching their required time zone and receive the objects with the appropriate data.

So say I have a table of Bookings for particular times. A couple of rows might look like

```
BookingId | When                    | TimeZone | Notes
        1 | 2011-05-06 12:00:00.000 | GMT +12  | null
        2 | 2011-05-06 08:00:00.000 | GMT +2   | null
```

The client would call something like `GetBookings("Pacific Standard Time")` and the resulting entity would be the above 2 tuples (probably without the time zone field) with their DateTimes adjusted such that the times are given in the client's time zone, with no additional time zone/offset information.

I know I could just do the time zone conversion on the client, but if I have multiple different clients I'm looking at duplicating this (somewhat tricky) code on multiple platforms, which I don't want to do.

The problem here is that if the server makes changes to these entities (which are backed by EF) then the changes are tracked by the ObjectContext. I'm sure there's a simple way around this?

The best solution I have thought of so far is a DTO for my Booking object, which I'd rather avoid but will implement if necessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one approach will be you can simply create a new object of that class type and copy the data from your "real" object to this one and modify this object's timestamp. Offcourse you should not add this to ObjectContext :p. If you return this object it will be simply good and you can achieve your results.

A better solution will be just create partial class for your class (Mindwell it should be in the same namespace) and create a computed property. If you are using Silverlight use `[DataMemberAttribute()]`  on the property and populate your information accordingly with your desired timezone. I think this is good to go.

Comment: The first solution is not ideal because it could confused other programmers working on the client if some objects are (seemingly arbitrarily) not attached to the object context when sent down the wire. I'll look into your second solution when I head to work this morning and let you know :)